# What should I Use for push notification in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have android application such a way that If user send feedback to another user then that `receiver` user gets `notification` about it, same like whatsapp.

What should i use for that ?
If `Google Cloud Messaging` good option or anything else is there ?

Comment: I dont think GoogleCloudMessage allows you to send directly msg to any user. Is it so ? Here is an alternative way, http://quickblox.com/developers/Android

Comment: why you cant write a service by your own, that will be the good option

Comment: if your app is only for android then you can use GCM but if you want cross platform messages i.e from android to ios and ios to android you can use urbanairship.

Comment: @Sreekanthss, it is not big application, It is like for college students. And I don't have that much time to make my own service.

Comment: ok look this http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139  some times help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three approaches:

1. Polling. It means your client application should periodically send request to server to get new Events. 
   [ bad bad approach!]
2. Steady connection. Your client application have a steady connection and list for server notifications. [inefficient for battery]

   - Because HTTP protocol is just for request-response, it's tricky to handle push. you have to have two connection to communicate with server. one for requests and another for handling server's events. you make a `keep-alive` connection to server, and server does not respond until it has some events for you, as soon as your client get the response(which is not actually a response!) your client must send another request to server to listen for future events. [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) protocol is a good option for this approach. there is also a java library called [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) and and android optimized ported library called [aSmack](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack). you must have an XMPP server too.
   - Use [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol which provides providing full-duplex communications channels over a single TCP connection. There is an android library called [android-websockets](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets) (and other java libs!)
3. [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) known as GCM

I think a combination of GCM and WebSocket is a good approach.

Comment: does GCM need internet connection to receive push message ?

Comment: Internet connection is necessary. but your client could be not connected to your server. your server just send new events to google server, and because google has a connection with your device (as long as your device is connected to the internet!), google send it to your client phone and android start your `Reciver`.

Comment: thank you. I have used GCM in past but don't have that much idea and that time i was new to android.